# Como redirecionar site para versão desktop?

Tags: php, redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url

Meu site tem duas versões: Desktop e Mobile.

Quando eu acesso pelo celular "www.meusite.com.br", sou redirecionado para a versão mobile: "m.meusite.com.br".

Para fazer isso, eu estou usando esse projeto muito legal chamado [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/)

Até aí tudo bem.

O site na versão Mobile, tem um botão para acessar a versão Desktop "Mudar para versão Desktop". E é aí que vem o problema.

Quando eu clico no botão para acessar a versão Desktop, eu sou redirecionado do "m.meusite.com.br" para o "www.meusite.com.br". A página é carregada e o script do `Mobile Detect` novamente é carregado e eu sou redirecionado para o "m.meusite.com.br" novamente. Ou seja, entra em loop.

Para exemplificar melhor:

---> Botão "Mudar para versão Desktop" é clicado;
---> A página é redirecionada para o "www.meusite.com.br";
---> A página "www" é carregada;
---> Como eu estou pelo celular e estou no "www.", o script Mobile Detect novamente é carregado e volto para o "m.meusite.com.br";

Código do site versão **Desktop**:

```
<?php
  require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
  $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf8">
  <?php if( $detect->isMobile() ) : ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         window.location.href = "http://m.meusite.com.br";  
    </script>

  <?php endif ?>

 </head>
<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0">

<div class="wrapper" style="height: 100vh; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; flex-direction: column">
  <h1>VERSÃO DESKTOP</h1>      
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Código do site versão **Mobile**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
    <div class="wrapper" style="height: 100vh; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; flex-direction: column">
      <h1>VERSÃO MOBILE</h1>
      <?php    
          require_once "../Mobile_Detect.php";
          $detect = New Mobile_Detect;

           if( $detect->isMobile() && (!isset($_GET['force_desktop']) || $_GET['force_desktop'] == 'false')) : ?>
               <a href="http://www.meusite.com.br&force_desktop=true">REDIRECIONAR PARA DESKTOP</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Pensando numa lógica de forçar a página a ficar na versão desktop quando eu estiver pelo celular, eu estou utilizando esse código dentro o botão que redirecionar para o desktop:

```
 if( $detect->isMobile() && (!isset($_GET['force_desktop']) || $_GET['force_desktop'] == 'false')) : ?>
     <a href="http://www.meusite.com.br&force_desktop=true?">REDIRECIONAR PARA DESKTOP</a>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Porém, ele dá erro de página não encontrada. Creio que estou errando no parâmetro a passar na URL.

Como posso resolver isso?
Como posso forçar o redirecionamento para a versão Desktop quando eu estiver pelo celular?

Comment: Com cookie, crie uma flag para identificar que não deve ser redirecionado.

Comment: Sua url está errada, você inverteu o `&` eo `?` , tenta assim `http://www.meusite.com.br/?force_desktop=true`

Comment: Verdade. Eu troquei os símbolos. Obrigado. Eu consegui resolver meu problema com  código do @Talisson. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o valor do seu GET existe, se ele existir a verificação do dispositivo não é feita.

```
<?php
  require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
  $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf8">

  <?php if( !isset($_GET['force_desktop']) && empty($_GET['force_desktop'])) : ?>

  <?php if( $detect->isMobile() ) : ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         window.location.href = "http://m.meusite.com.br";  
    </script>

  <?php endif ?>
  <?php endif ?>
  <?php var_dump($_GET); ?>
 </head>
<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0">

<div class="wrapper" style="height: 100vh; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; flex-direction: column">
  <h1>VERSÃO DESKTOP</h1>     
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda cara! Que erro bobo. Eu estava fazendo a verificação na página no `index` da "m.meusite..". O correto era fazer na `index` do desktop. E claro, antes da condição que verifica se estou num dispositivo móvel. Bem simples, muito obrigado!